# Files upload with ssh?

Tags: ssh, upload

Can I upload files to a server without using ftp or sftp ?

Just with ssh ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ssh is a connection method but inherently does not 'do' file transfers. You could run commands like tar and cat via ssh but there are specific utilities that are better suited to file transfers with ssh - have a look at [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) and [rsync](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/38).

Comment: essentially `scp` and `rsync` do not differ from `tar` since they ALL tunnel via ssh. especially `rsync` talks to its counterpart exactly the same way as does `tar`: via a pipe...

Answer (score 10):

All SSH implementations I know *do* include SFTP, so I don't see why would you not want to use it.

Anyway:

```
(cd sourcedir && tar cf - file otherfile) | ssh host "cd targetdir && tar xvf -"
```

Or for a single file, without preserving metadata:

```
ssh host "cat > targetfile" < sourcefile
```

Comment: tar cf - file -C sourcedir ...